# how to update & delete after inserting data

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have 3 table

- book (buku)
- transaction (transaksi)
- return (pengembalian)

so when i save data from table transaction(transaksi), it will inserting into table return(pengembalian). after that i want the table book(buku) updating its "stock" column by +1 and deleting the data from table transaction(transaksi)

i've tried to put these inside the function save, but it doesnt work

```
$this->db->set('jumlah_buku', 'jumlah_buku+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('id', $data1);
        $this->db->update('tb_buku');
```

this is the query, i don't know how to implementing it

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE `tb_buku` SET `jumlah_buku`=(jumlah_buku+1) WHERE id = '$id_buku'");
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM tb_transaksi WHERE id_transaksi = '$id_transaksi'");
```

controller

```
public function simpan(){
        $data1 = [
            "id_transaksi"  => $this->input->post('id_transaksi'),
            "kode_buku"     => $this->input->post('id_buku'),
            "nis"           => $this->input->post('nis'),
            "nama"          => $this->input->post('nama'),
            "tanggal_kembali"   => $this->input->post('tglkembali'),
            "status_denda"          => $this->input->post('status_denda'),
            "keterangan"            => $this->input->post('keterangan')
        ];      
        $this->Kembali_models->save($data1);
        $result = $this->db->affected_rows();
```

model

```
public function save($data1){
        $this->db->insert('tb_pengembalian', $data1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For update the data, use this :

```
$this->db->set('jumlah_buku', 'jumlah_buku+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', $data1['id_buku']);
$this->db->update(tb_buku'); // produce ""UPDATE `tb_buku` SET `jumlah_buku`=(jumlah_buku+1) WHERE id = '$id_buku'
```

To delete the Data, use this

```
$this->db->delete('tb_transaksi', array(id_transaksi => '$id_transaksi'")); // produce " DELETE FROM tb_transaksi WHERE id_transaksi = '$id_transaksi"
```

Write after inserting data :)